# python: what does array([...]) mean?

Tags: python, arrays, list

i am working with lists, and there is a function that is returning something that looks like this:

```
array([0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2])
```

how do i cast those values into a `list`?

what does `array` mean?

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  Where did you see this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array` most likely refers to a `numpy.array`

```
myarray = array([0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2])
mylist = list(myarray)
```

Comment: for small arrays (30 elements or so on this computer) `myarray.tolist()` is faster